# shortest path from A to B without superfluous edges (in Java)

Tags: java, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I have an assignment where I need to build a simple undirected graph, calculate the path between two  points, and calculate the capacity of the resulting path.

I've gotten the capacity calculation working. And the path printout shows that a path between two points can also be found, but I can't get rid of edges resulting in dead-ends without breaking my code entirely. I've tried specifying bouncing back from dead-ends, but i hasn't worked so far. Any path using multiple-edged vertexes currently shows all of the edges connected to that vertex, whether or not that point is in the middle of the path or set as start/end.  Basically, it covers all of the edges in-between the given points, even the superfluous ones.

My code so far is below. My attempts at removing the dead-end edges from the path are commented out, but still there.

Can anyone help me with fixing this?

---

```
  public Queue<Edge> SearchPaths(Vertex x, Vertex eelmine) {

      if(visited.isEmpty())
          lopp = x; // ?? start = x; ??

      if(visited.indexOf(x) > -1) 
          return null;

      if(x.isEquals(lopp)) {
          Edge serv = x.leiaServ(eelmine);
          if(serv != null)
              rajad.add(serv);
      }

      Edge serv = x.first;
      while (serv != null) {
          if(visited.indexOf(serv.target) == -1)
              if(serv != null)
                  rajad.add(serv);
          serv = serv.next; // ?? serv += serv.next
      }
      visited.add(x);

      // otsi uuest tipust järgmine serv
      if(visited.indexOf(x.first.target) == -1) {
          Vertex jarg = x.first.target;

      Edge uusserv = jarg.leiaServ(x);
      if(uusserv != null)
          rajad.add(uusserv);
      SearchPaths(jarg, x);


          /* "dead-end edges" .. not correct, breaks code

          // nt. x=C, jarg=D, D != lopp ... jarg.jarg == C (C-D-C)
          if(jarg!=lopp && visited.indexOf(jarg.first.target) != -1)
                  jarg.equals(x);

          // x=C, jarg=E, E == lopp ... x == jarg
          // x=C, jarg=A, A != lopp ... jarg.jarg == B (C-A-B)
          if(jarg!=lopp && visited.indexOf(jarg.first.target) == -1) {
              jarg.leiaServ(x);
              rajad.add(serv);
              x.equals(jarg);   // liiguta x edasi
              SearchPaths(jarg, x);
          }*/
      }
      return rajad;
  }
} // Vertex ehk Tipp
```

Comment: This is not a "do my work for me site", and copy-pasting massive amounts of code is **not** appreciated. Reduce your code to the  minimum required to demonstrate your question!

Answer (score 3):

If you implemented it using a priority queue, see [Djikstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), you only need to put an "infinite" weight on the path that has reached the dead end and it won't be visited again.

A "min" priority queue is a datastructure that pops the element with the least weight attached to it. So when you're traversing, you build up the queue for each traversal (by walking to the node's neighbours). So if you've reached a node that either has:

- no edges (is a leaf node)
- edges to nodes you've already traversed (in order to avoid the roundabout cyclic traversal)

Then you only need to put a maxed out weight on the path. In Java you would use [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) for `int` or [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) for `long`.